# How to create design without applying float in parent div or without adding clear both in div?

Tags: html, css

[image]

We want design like #2 but we are facing #1 design issue. when we are apply float left in parent div (gray border div) then its work fine. if any one have solution without applying float in parent div or without adding clear both in div then please let me know.

For more information please check attached image.(Float.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

```css
div{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid red;
  
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: With Out Floating way is Override Its Default Styles .

Answer (score 0):

Add overflow: hidden to the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .parent > div {
            margin : 10px;
            width:80px;
            height:80px;
            border:1px solid red;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="parent" style="display:flex;">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also use flex by adding style as display:flex in parent div

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below code

HTML

```
<div class="outer-div">

<div class="inner-div"></div>
<div class="inner-div"></div>
<div class="inner-div"></div>
<div class="inner-div"></div>
<div class="inner-div"></div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
body,html{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background:#f1f1f1;
}


.outer-div{
  border:2px solid #ccc;
  padding:10px;
  height:auto;
  width:350px
}

.inner-div{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid red;  
}
```

code pan link

http://codepen.io/santoshkhalse/pen/XjjLKz